# Summation of rows of a matrix P^k is decreasing with the power k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

I have the following $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
f(0) & g(0) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
f(1) & 0 & g(1) & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
f(2) & 0 & 0 & g(2) & 0 & \dots & 0\\
f(3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & g(3) & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & & & & \ddots & 0\\
f(n-1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots & g(n-1)\\
f(n)  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $0< f(x)< 1$, $0< g(x)< 1$, and $f(x)+g(x)<1$, $f(x)$ is increasing, $g(x)$ is decreasing. Also, $g(x)$ decreases faster than $f(x)$ is increasing, so their sum $f(x)+g(x)$ is decreasing.

I want to show that by raising $P$ to any power $k$, the summation of the elements of the $i$-th row, i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} P^{k}_{i,j}$ is decreasing with $i$.

I have taken the following inductive approach:

- I know that the summation of the *rows* of $P^t$ is decreasing when $t=1$, since $f(x)+g(x)$ is decreasing.
- Suppose that the summation of the rows of $P^t$ is decreasing up to $t=k-1$. I want to show that it holds for $t=k$.
- The $i$-th row of $P^k$ can be written as follows:
  \begin{equation} P^k_{i,:} = P_{i,:} P^{k-1} \end{equation}
  from which the summation is derived as
  \begin{equation} \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} P^k_{i,j} = f(i)\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} P^{k-1}_{1,j} + g(i)\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} P^{k-1}_{i+1,j}. \end{equation}

I cannot get past this point.

Also, I haven't found any way to compute a closed-form expression of $P^k$, although it has a very specific structure: it is the concatenation of a non-zero column-row pair (the first column and the last row) and a diagonal matrix.

Edit: I do not care about the summation of the last row, only for all the $n$ first rows.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it's true? Can you prove it for $k=2$? Can you prove it for $n=1$?

Comment: MathJax note: use `-`, not `$\bullet$`, for bulleted lists; and `*text*`, not `$text$`, for italic text.  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample is given by
$$P=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
so that then
$$P^2=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

---

Here the conditions on $P$ are satisfied only non-strictly. However, by approximation, this does not matter. For instance, one may replace $P$ by the close matrix
$$P_h=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 h & 1-2h & 0 \\
 2 h & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
for small enough $h>0$.
Then $P_h$ will strictly satisfy all the conditions on $f$ and $g$, and yet $P_h^2$ will be arbitrarily close to $P^2$, and hence your desired conclusion will fail to hold.

---

The OP has changed the question, now saying " I do not care about the summation of the last row, only for all the n first rows."

Then a counterexample is
$$P=\frac1{100}\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 98 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 50 & 0 & 0 \\
 25 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 0 \\
 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 49 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
so that $P^2$ is bad: the sum of the 2nd row of $P^2$ ($\approx0.27$) is less than the sum of the 3rd row of $P^2$ ($\approx0.37$).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The examples that you gave do not satisfy the requirement that f(x) + g(x) < 1.

Comment: @K.Bountrogiannis : Ah, OK. What about now? (As I said, the strictness does not matter anyway.)

Comment: I edited my post. In particular, I don't care about the decreasing property on the last row, only up to the previous n rows.

Comment: @K.Bountrogiannis : You should not change your post so as to invalidate a valid answer. Please restore the original post.

Comment: Then should I open a new question? Because this is the actual problem I have at hand.

Comment: @K.Bountrogiannis : I have answered (again negatively) the changed question as well. However, in the future do not change your questions like this.

Comment: I see, OK I will keep it in mind. On your new answer, I can observe that between the second and the third row, f(x) increases faster than g(x) decreases. More importantly, is there a reason to be inclined to the negative answer? Thank you.

Comment: @K.Bountrogiannis : You wrote: "between the second and the third row, f(x) increases faster than g(x) decreases". This is not true. Between the second and third rows, $f$ increases by $23/100$ and $g$ decreases by $25/100$. You also wrote: "More importantly, is there a reason to be inclined to the negative answer?" I don't know if such a reason exists. Initially, I was not inclined either way. The answer has just turned out to be negative, even after your change of the question.

Comment: You are correct, I was hasty while reading the matrix. So it seems that it needs additional assumption in order to prove this. Do you have any idea to this end?

Comment: @K.Bountrogiannis : Frankly, I don't think this is salvageable. Hopefully, this negative result will help you move in a more fruitful direction.